# Bitcoin / DefiChain RPC rawTransaction

Tags: cryptography, rpc

Hello i try to figure out how to encode normal rpc calls in an raw transaction.
Till now my problem is that i dont know what the hex must contain as string.
f.e.

```
rpc command:  "method: 'compositeswap' {'from':'MyAddress','tokenFrom':'MyToken1','amountFrom':'0.001','to':'Address','tokenTo':'Token2','maxPrice':'0.01'}"
```

There seems to be OP-Codes to exists like *OP_DEFI_TX_COMPOSITE_SWAP*
how does the chain knows to execute an operation with params?

i tried to figure it out by trying to decode an actual transaction from the test wallet:
from the part

```
 "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_RETURN 446654786917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000",
        "hex": "6a4c50446654786917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000",
        "type": "nulldata"
      },
```

of

```
{
  "txid": "9a98d693d4c5107647131ee1bb7a5b0cce0fcdbe390c9609a71f4b71157e39dc",
  "hash": "a18a6fd4abf0ba1885febcf37a333b1d1f34b4de954f13538a6619b1d7b20042",
  "version": 4,
  "size": 309,
  "vsize": 228,
  "weight": 909,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "9e1140197138ba5e247ab3b3f1f4881bf7be624a939073d9795242caf3634409",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "0014451be7ab94ccd7eff0a33ab8fe997a75c62eb7dd",
        "hex": "160014451be7ab94ccd7eff0a33ab8fe997a75c62eb7dd"
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "30440220552d8aa4e129f566bfe083b780e1dcf67a3ca0176e07407912451371f597bc620220698c6ac483e021b78c7d7bf42e14f1c619618d1941cf12fec7cf8302ece6d3ae01",
        "03c7d2dbe5ee429de5d88e8594cda6ceb84268ebbf9d0b16b33664e999307f33e8"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_RETURN 446654786917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000",
        "hex": "6a4c50446654786917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000",
        "type": "nulldata"
      },
      "tokenId": 0
    },
    {
      "value": 183.03901748,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c87",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "tgfbETCK2kYyvsnHbS41v9aicQzAXLsz9B"
        ]
      },
      "tokenId": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

the

```
OP_RETURN 446654786917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000
```

cant be decoded sucessfully back into a string.
does s.o know what kind of encoding it is?
tried

```
bytess=bytes.fromhex("446654786917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000")
print(bytess.decode("latin-1"))
```

but only get

```
INFO (MainThread) 14.05.2022 22:02:39 DfTxi©r
INFO (MainThread) 14.05.2022 22:02:39 [
INFO (MainThread) 14.05.2022 22:02:39 XÓŠ÷¶y{8[jÂ‘°øŒ‡  áõ    ©r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just decode the string after the OP Code. It is a concatenation of several input parameters depending on the function.
In your example

```
6a4c50446654786917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000
```

6a is OP_RETURN
4c50 is Number of bytes following (in HEX)
44665478 is "DfTx" in HEX
6917a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870000e1f5050000000017a914721d5b1c58d38af7b6797b385b6ac291b002f88c870b0000000000000000c74e71050000000000 = the parameters from your json. For your address you need Base58 (in this case) or Bech32 encoding to get the hex (some backward engineering necessary).
The part with lots of zeros is the amount/maxPrice.
The tokens are inserted by their IDs not the name.

I am thinking about writing a guide. So far, I am afraid you have to do some backward engineering. Hope this helps a little bit

Comment: Actually the second byte 0x4c is OP_PUSHDATA1 and then just third byte 0x50 is the size (80 bytes). It's needed because in one push 75 bytes is the max. See https://wiki.bitcoinsv.io/index.php/Pushdata_Opcodes